# Jquery 'addClass' sometimes fails but css does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

in some cases, this will not work:

```
("#id").addClass("class");
```

whereas this will:

```
("#id").css('color','Blue');
```

why would it fail and how to add class otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

Key concept: **CSS Specificity**

> From CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know:
>
> 1. Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers.
> 2. Specificity is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don’t apply to some elements, although you think they should.
> 3. Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy.
> 4. If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.
> 5. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector: inline styles, IDs, classes+attributes and elements.
>      ...

#### Nice little [cheatsheet](http://www.vcarrer.com/2009/09/css-specificity-cheat-sheet.html):

[image: CSS Specificity Cheat Sheet]
<sub>(source: [allapis.com](http://www.allapis.com/CSS-Specificity-Cheat-Sheet/CSS-specificity-cheat-sheet.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If there is an ***inline styling*** applied then addClass may fail.

Sample

```
$(function() {
    $("#ul1 li a" ).hover(
       function () {
           $(this).css('color','red');
       }, 
       function () {
           $(this).css('color','blue');
       }
    );
});

<ul id="ul1">
    <li>
        <a href="#">test
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also use [**toggleClass**](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass) method to do this.

Comment: Or even a stronger CSS rule. It's a css fail. +1.

Comment: in my case i have inline <li> <a> </li>  how can i change hover color on the a tag with the css function?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the class has pre-existing styles applying to it that supersede the properties of the class you have added. Though, I only suggest this because you show using .css as a tactic that always works. If the object is simply not getting the class added to it at all, I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because when a class is already applied, it won't be applied again. Jquery checks that. The css method applies without looking at what are the previous styles.

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing,  try  something like

```
 ("#id").addClass("test");
```

Now check with Firebug / IE dev toolbar if this dummy "test" class is getting applied or not.